# Yelp API, OAuth; Invalid signature. Expected signature base string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth, yelp

NOTE: I've looked at all the posts on the first two pages of Google search results returned when I type my error into Google and I still have this issue. It seems there's not a lot of coverage on JavaScript OAuth stuff because most OAuth business takes place on the back end.

I'm trying to make an AJAX request to the Yelp Phone Search API. I'm using [Marco Bettiolo's JavaScript OAuth library](https://github.com/bettiolo/oauth-signature-js). I believe I've got the OAuth library working, but for some reason when I try to make the call, the JSON being returned speaks of an "Invalid Signature" error. Go ahead and check out my [live project](http://jvojens2.github.io/frontend-nanodegree-neighborhood-map/) and see the error for yourself. Here's my [project on GitHub](https://github.com/jvojens2/frontend-nanodegree-neighborhood-map). If you want to reproduce the error yourself, go to my [live project](http://jvojens2.github.io/frontend-nanodegree-neighborhood-map/), open up devtools console, click on a gym so that an infoWindow pops up, and then click on where it says, "Click Here to See Photos." Once you click on that, the application will fire off the AJAX request and keep your eye on the console, because you will see the error show up.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here's the relevant code. I've placed the AJAX-relevant code inside the onclick handler for the photos link that's in each infoWindow.

```
photoLink.onclick = function() {
    // Modify phone number string so it's ready to be 
    // put into url for AJAX call to Yelp API
    var phoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
    var re = /\D/gi; 
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(re, '');

    var yelpURL = YELP_BASE_URL + phoneNumber;

    var parameters = {
      oauth_consumer_key: YELP_CONSUMER_KEY,
      oauth_token: YELP_TOKEN,
      oauth_nonce: generateNonce(),
      oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000),
      oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      oauth_version : '1.0',
      callback: 'cb'              // This is crucial to include for jsonp implementation in 
                                  // AJAX or else the oauth-signature will be wrong.
    };

    var encodedSignature = oauthSignature.generate('GET',yelpURL, parameters, YELP_CONSUMER_SECRET, YELP_TOKEN_SECRET);
    parameters.oauth_signature = encodedSignature;

    var settings = {
      url: yelpURL,
      data: parameters,
      cache: true,  //        <----  This is crucial to include as well to prevent jQuery from 
                                  // adding on a cache-buster parameter "_=23489489749837", 
                                  // invalidating our oauth-signature
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(results) {
        // Do stuff with results
        console.log(results);
      },
      fail: function() {
        // Do stuff on fail
        console.log('AJAX request has failed :(');
      }
    };

    // Send AJAX request via jQuery library
    $.ajax(settings);
  };
```

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery ajax settings, you will also need to specify the callback name to match your callback parameter when generating signature. Otherwise, jQuery will just pick a random name which causes the invalid signature.

Try adding this to your settings:

```
jsonpCallback: 'cb'
```

Hope this helps.